# JS promise losing data variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, promise, async-await

I faced an issue with this promise. After forEach with function that returns object of users, the variable of arrays (clients) becomes empty ( [] ). Ngl I don't have a single clue how to solve this problem. Thanks for your time :))

```
function getAdminUsers(adminGroups) {
        return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
          try {
            var clients = new Array();
            console.log(adminGroups);
            await adminGroups.forEach(async (group) => {
              clients[group] = await teamspeak.serverGroupClientList(group);
            });
            console.log('CLIENTS', clients);
            resolve(clients);
          } catch (error) {
            handleServerQueryError(error);
          }
        });
      }
```

adminGroups array:

```
module.exports = {
  adminGroups: [6, 277, 14, 18, 17, 16, 13, 528, 568],
};
```

the terminal output:

```
New user connected from 188.146.229.188
[
    6, 277, 14,  18,
   17,  16, 13, 528,
  568
]
CLIENTS []
```

Comment: This construct `await adminGroups.forEach(...)` doesn't work. Either use a regular loop with `await` or check out [Promise#all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

Comment: And please don't do this `new Promise(async ...)` every `async function` will **always** return a Promise. So what do you need `new Promise()` for? Plus, in your particular case, the part with `catch (error)` will create a memory leak as it doesn't ever settle the `new Promise()` you've created.

Comment: @Thomas Never-resolved promises don't leak memory, they're garbage-collected like everything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for the [Promise constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it) in your code, and you seem to be assigning items into an array using what could be property names rather than indexes (`forEach((group, idx)` and using `idx` is probably what you would want, or `clients.push`). There's no need create a `new Array` and push to it though, when you can use [`Promise.all` on a `.map`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65876058/5774952).

```
async function getAdminUsers(adminGroups) {
  try {
    const clients = await Promise.all(
      adminGroups.map(async (group) => {
        const list = await teamspeak.serverGroupClientList(group)
        return list
      })
    )
    return clients
  } catch (error) {
    handleServerQueryError(error)
  }
}
```

Comment: What about `adminGroups.map(group => teamspeak.serverGroupClientList(group))` would this work?

Comment: Yes @Thomas - good point. that would work for sure.

Comment: @Thomas That would work, there are people that prefer either style of writing

Comment: Yeah, since it's returning a promise either way and and it's wrapped in the Promise.all, that should work just the same.

Answer (score 2):

`forEach()` isn't async. [It returns `undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#return_value), which, because you `await` it, converts automatically to `Promise` that immediately resolves to `undefined`. The callbacks are run, but you don't wait for them to finish.

There are two different things you can do to `await` some `Promises`:

If you want for them to run one-after-one (like `forEach()`), you can use a `for`-`of` loop. Also note that I removed the `return new Promise(async resolve => ...)`, because an async function always return a promise, so this is redundant.

```js
async function getAdminUsers(adminGroups) {
  try {
    var clients = new Array();
    console.log(adminGroups);
    for (const group of adminGroups) {
      clients[group] = await teamspeak.serverGroupClientList(group);
    }
    console.log('CLIENTS', clients);
    return clients;
  } catch (error) {
    handleServerQueryError(error);
  }
}
```

The other thing you can do is to use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) (or variants, like [`Promise.allSettled()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled)) to run the promises *in parallel*. It can look like:

```js
async function getAdminUsers(adminGroups) {
  try {
    var clients = new Array();
    console.log(adminGroups);
    await Promise.all(adminGroups.map(async group => {
      clients[group] = await teamspeak.serverGroupClientList(group);
    }));
    console.log('CLIENTS', clients);
    return clients;
  } catch (error) {
    handleServerQueryError(error);
  }
}
```

Comment: Using `.map` with a separate `clients` array in your second example is redundant, at that point it could just be `clients = await Promise.all...`

Comment: Not so, because in the original code not all indices of `clients` are assigned (there can be holes), and I wanted to preserve that

Comment: They're not ordered either.

Comment: Ah, I assumed that was also a bug and that what OP wanted was something more like `.forEach((group, i) => { clients[i] = ...`

Comment: Maybe, but that's not the OP's code precisely :P